# Editing Team Names in Perfect Dark

Tags: perfect-dark

I have a copy of *Perfect Dark* (for N64), but the previous owner seems to have entered some juvenile, how shall I say, less than polite terms for the team names. As such, whenever a challenge is played, these family-unfriendly terms are displayed.

I searched the game’s interface, but could not find anywhere in which team names could be modified. (I considered that the names were actually built-in considering the silly titles shown during the credits, but these terms are pretty vulgar and I highly doubt that they would have been allowed by Nintendo, even with a third-party game.)

How can the team names be modified in *Perfect Dark*? (Hopefully they can be modified without having to clear the whole cartridge since I recently finished playing through it and would rather avoid wiping out my save progress.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. The problem with *Perfect Dark* is that the menus are not only multi-level (a sub-menu pops up when you select a menu item), but also cyclical (pressing left/right rotates the current level menu). This makes it easy to miss entire menus.

To change team names in *Perfect Dark*:

1. Open the `Combat Simulator` from the *Perfect Menu*
2. Select *Advanced Setup*
3. Do **not** select `Teams` from the *Game Setup* sub-menu that pops up, that’s for configuring the teams themeselves, not the names
4. Instead, press <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> two times to switch to the ***Stuff*** sub-menu
5. Now select `Team Names` and press <kbd>A</kbd> to edit